# C# Winforms projects with Entity Framework as DAL - which .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework

I'm an experienced php developer and am attempting my hand at learning Microsoft Entity Framework.  My backend Database is Oracle and I'm using ODP.Net as my connection.  I've installed VS2019 Community and am working through several tutorials.

- [Oracle Entity Framework Core Introduction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RDZXJYLUC7I)
- [Entity Framework Best Practices](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qkJ9keBmQWo)
- [Microsoft Create a Data Access Layer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/create_the_data_access_layer)
- [EntityFrameworkCore](https://entityframeworkcore.com/)

I'm struggling with trying to have my C# library (DAL) work well with my C# winforms projects.  My DAL is a .NET Standard 2.0 project and my winforms projects is .NET Framework 4.7.2.  My solution is setup as follows.

- C# Solution

  - Project 1 - C# Library (DAL) - .NET Standard 2.0
  - Nuget Dependencies

    - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design (2.2.6)
    - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools (2.2.6)
    - Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore(2.19.60)
  - Project 2 - C# Winforms - .NET Framework 4.7.2
  - Nuget Dependencies

    - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore(2.2.6)
    - Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore(2.19.60)
    - Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core (2.19.60)

Code pieces of code are in the DAL (project 1)

DbContext

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {

            optionsBuilder.UseOracle(@"<myConnString>");
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new PlatePurchaseOrderConfiguration());
        }
        public DbSet<PlatePurchaseOrder> LtPurchaseOrders { get; set; }
    }
```

ModelConfiguration

```
class PlatePurchaseOrderConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<PlatePurchaseOrder>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<PlatePurchaseOrder> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(t => t.Id);
        }
    }
```

Model

```
public class PlatePurchaseOrder
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public bool IsExpeditied { get; set; }
        public DateTime ExpectedReturnDate { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the code behind the startup winforms (project 2)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var context = new PlatePurchaseOrderContext();
            var query = context.LtPurchaseOrders.ToList();
        }
    }
```

And upon running my code I get, an error at the `.ToList()` command of

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.0.3.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51
```

I have to imagine that I'm mixing projects and .NET components probably messing things up.  Is there a good way around this?  What should I be doing to correctly setup this Solution?

Comment: You need binding redirects or add that package explicitly to both assemblies. Also see https://medium.com/@RupaniChirag/how-to-resolve-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies-and-why-this-cf8d48d788eb

Comment: Also, since this is a new project, you might consider .NET 5 Preview 2 https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-5-0-preview-2/